React Native Swipe to delete functionality in a section list using RNGH Issue
I have a sectionlist with notifications and would like to have each row in a section be capable of swiping to delete. I have implemented the swipe to delete functionality but the issue I am facing now is that everytime I scroll down the sectionlist and a pan gesture is active on one of the rows, I cannot scrolling becomes disabled. Can anyone with experience guide me on this ? Happy to learn:)
import { View , Text, StyleSheet, Modal, Button, TouchableOpacity,SectionList} from "react-native";
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import { NotificationLikeStack } from "../../components/Stacks/NotificationStacks/NotificationLikeStack";  
import { NotificationCommentStack } from "../../components/Stacks/NotificationStacks/NotificationCommentStack"; 
import { fetchDocs, doDocsExist,deleteDocsFromDB,addDocsToDB, addDocToDB, addDocsWithDifferenDataToDB, fetchData } from "../../firebase/firestoreDB";
import { bottomPopUpMessage } from "../../constants";
import HorizontalScrollButton from "../../components/HorizontalScrollButton/HorizontalScrollButton";
import { Divider } from "@ui-kitten/components";
import { NotificationFollowersStack } from "../../components/Stacks/NotificationStacks/NotificationFollowersStack";
import { isToday } from "../../constants";
import { set } from "firebase/database";
import { handleSendPushNotification } from "../../constants";
import uuid from "react-native-uuid";
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';
import { FlatList, ScrollView,  } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

const NotifcationScreen = ({navigation, route}) => { 
    const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([])
    const [filteredNotifications, setFilteredNotifications] = useState([notifications])
    const buttons = ['All', 'Likes', 'Comments', 'Followers']
    const [selectedButton, setSelectedButton] = useState(null)
    const userinfo = useSelector((state) => state.auth.userInfo)
    const [email, setEmail] = useState(userinfo?.email)
    const [filterButtonPressed, setFilterButtonPressed] = useState(false)
    const [usersBeingFollowed, setUsersBeingFollowed] = useState([])
    const [hasPressedFollowButton, setHasPressedFollowButton] = useState(false)
    const LinkingUrl = Linking.useURL();
    const sectionListRef = useRef(null)
    const [isScrollEnabled, setIsScrollEnabled] = useState(true)
    // const section = notifications ? [
    //     {
    //         title: 'Likes',
    //         data: notifications.filter((notification) => notification.type === 'like')
    //     },
    //     {
    //         title: 'Comments',
    //         data: notifications.filter((notification) => notification.type === 'comment')
    //     },
    //     {
    //         title: 'Followers',
    //         data: notifications.filter((notification) => notification.type === 'follow')
    //     }
    // ] : []

    const section = notifications ? [
      {
        title: 'Today',
        data: !filterButtonPressed ? notifications.filter(
          (notification) =>  isToday(notification.createdAt)
        ) : filteredNotifications.filter( (notification) => isToday(notification.createdAt)),
      },
      {
        title: 'Older',
        data: !filterButtonPressed ? notifications.filter(
          (notification) => !isToday(notification.createdAt)
        ) : filteredNotifications.filter( (notification) => !isToday(notification.createdAt)),
      }
    ]
  : [];



    const fetchNotifications = async () => {
        const path = `users/${email}/notifications`
        const response = await fetchDocs(path)
        if (response.success){
            setNotifications(response.fetchedDocs.reverse())
        }
        else{
            bottomPopUpMessage(response)
        }
    }
    
    const renderItem = ({ item }) => {  
        if (item.type === 'like'){
            return (
                <NotificationLikeStack notification={item} onPressed={() => {
                    
                    navigation.navigate("HomeScreen", item.params)
                }}/>
            )
        }
        else if (item.type === 'comment'){
            return (
                item.params.type === "polls" ? 
                <NotificationCommentStack notification={item} onPressed={() => navigation.navigate("HomeScreen",item.params) }/> 
                : <NotificationLikeStack setIsScrollEnabled={setIsScrollEnabled} notification={item} onPressed={() => {    
                    navigation.navigate("HomeScreen", item.params)
                }}/>
            )
        }
        else if (item.type === 'follow'){
            const isFollowing = usersBeingFollowed.includes(item.followID)
            return (
                <NotificationFollowersStack 
                notification={item} 
                isFollowing={isFollowing}
                onPressFollowButton={() => {
                    onPressFollow(item, isFollowing)    
                }
                }
                onPressed={async () => {
                    const params = await redirectedProfileHandler(item.followID)
                    navigation.navigate("Profile", params)
                }}
                />
            )
        }

    }


    useEffect(() => {
        fetchNotifications()
    }, [])


    //console.log(notifications)
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{marginHorizontal: 20}}>
                <HorizontalScrollButton
                    buttons={buttons}
                    onButtonPress={handleButtonPress}
                    selectedButton={selectedButton}
                    setSelectedButton={setSelectedButton}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={{backgroundColor:'green'}}>
            <SectionList
            SectionSeparatorComponent={renderSectionSeparator}
            stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
            sections={section}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
            renderItem={({item}) => renderItem({item})}
            renderSectionHeader={({section: {title, data}}) => {
                if ( data.length === 0) {
                    return null; // Don't render the header if there are no likes
                  }
                  return <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>; 
            }}
            scrollEnabled={isScrollEnabled}
            ref={sectionListRef}
            style={{}}
            />  
            </View>
   
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        //marginHorizontal: 0
        //marginHorizontal: 16,
    },
    header: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        //backgroundColor: '#fff',
        margin:20,
      },
})

export default NotifcationScreen;

import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { Image } from 'expo-image';
import { ImageDict } from '../../../constants';
import { CustomButtons } from '../../buttons/Buttons';
import { handleTimePosted } from '../../../constants';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Gesture, GestureDetector } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated,{ runOnJS, useAnimatedStyle, withSpring, useSharedValue} from 'react-native-reanimated';

export const NotificationFollowersStack = ({imageExtraStyle, notification, isFollowing, onPressFollowButton, onPressed }) => {
    const profilePic = notification.profilePic ? notification.profilePic : ImageDict.user
    const translateX = useSharedValue(0);

    const animatedStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
        transform: [{ translateX: withSpring(translateX.value) }],
    }));

    const gesture = Gesture.Pan().
        onBegin(() => {
            console.log(translateX.value);
        }).
        onChange((event) => {   
            
            if (event.translationX < 0){
                translateX.value = -50;
            }
            if (event.translationX > 0){
                translateX.value = 0;
            }
            //translateX.value = event.translationX;
        }).
        onFinalize(() => { 
            console.log(translateX.value);
            //translateX.value = withSpring(10);
        })

        const onPressOptionsClose = () => {
            set
        }

        return (
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <GestureDetector 
            gesture={gesture}
            >
            <Animated.View style={[styles.container, animatedStyles]} onPress={onPressed}>
                    <Image
                    style={[styles.profileImageStyles, imageExtraStyle]}
                    source={profilePic}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.textStackContainer}>
                        <Text>
                            <Text style={styles.userhandle}>{notification.userhandle}</Text> {notification.title} 
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.timeStyle}>{handleTimePosted(notification.createdAt)}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                        {!isFollowing ? 
                        <CustomButtons 
                        name={"follow-long"} 
                        extraStyle={styles.followButtonStyle} 
                        onPress={onPressFollowButton}/> :
                            <CustomButtons 
                            name={"unfollow-long"} 
                            extraStyle={styles.followButtonStyle} 
                            onPress={onPressFollowButton}/>
                            }
                    </View>
            </Animated.View>
            </GestureDetector>
            <View style={styles.deleteStyles}>
                <View style={{position:"absolute", right:5}}>
                <Ionicons name="trash-sharp" size={24} color="black" />
                </View>
                <View style={{backgroundColor:"white", position:"absolute", left:0, top:0, bottom:0, height:'100%', width:"50%"}}/>
            </View>
            </View>
        )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        //alignItems:'center',
        justifyContent:'space-between',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        width: '100%',
        padding: 20,
        zIndex: 1,
        //margin: 20,
    },
    textStackContainer: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        //backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        flex: 1,
        paddingLeft: 10,
        paddingRight: 10,
        //padding: 10
        //alignItems: 'center',
    },
    profileImageStyles: {
        height:50,
        width:50,
        borderRadius:25,
    },
    deleteStyles:{
        position: 'absolute',
        right: 0,
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        //bottom: 10,
        zIndex: 0,
        justifyContent:'center',
        backgroundColor:'red',
        paddingRight: 0,
    },
    imageStyles: {
        height:50,
        width:50,
        borderRadius:5,
    },
    userhandle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    timeStyle: {
        color:'grey',
        marginTop: 5,
        //marginLeft:10
    },
    followButtonStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#FF6657',
        width: 80,
        height: 40,
        borderRadius: 10,
    },
})```

